# Miswired 3-way switches

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch

I've encountered a pair of 3-way switches that exhibit the following behavior:

[image]

In switch #2, the wire on the common is white with black tape. When I disconnect all wires on the switches, that's the only wire that's hot. I can't get to the light since it's a cathedral ceiling lamp.

Comment: Pictures, with the wires connected as they originally were, would be best. Second best would be a list of which color wires on which cables are connected to each screw of each switch. You likely have either 2 or 3 cables involved - one between the switches, one to light + power (I suspect that is the case because of white marked as black) and possible one more.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: Ah. Switch loop with 3-ways? But if properly wired, shouldn't the convention be that the relabelled white in that loop is _switched_ hot returned from the switches rather than hot? I am definitely missing at least one step.

Comment: As I understand it, with a traditional switch loop, convention is that white comes down from the light fixture box as *hot*, marked black to indicate it is hot and not neutral, it goes "into" the switch (or in this case, the 3-way switch conglomeration) and goes back to the light fixture on black as *switched hot*. The reason, as explained to me by Harper a long time ago, is that since a non-contact voltage tester will be used for safety, this ensures that the white is actually hot if the circuit is on so that it is obvious from NCVT testing that it is not neutral. Otherwise, switch turned off

Comment: and you check the white wire and find it dead you *assume* "must be neutral" and then someone turns on the switch and...ZAP! If instead white is hot (marked black but black tape falls off...) when you test it with NCVT you will get "hot" and know it isn't a puny neutral. As in [this diagram](https://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/light-switch-wiring-diagrams)

Comment: Ah. I was misremembering, thanks. Note that the table above is a logical or, which suggests someone wired these switches in parallel rather than crossed-series as would be normal for 3-way.

Comment: You're making more of this than there is.  Miswired 3-ways are common as dirt.  And there are only 3 possible ways they can be wired once you know how they work.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica So is it possible to say which particular miswiring would cause the behavior above?

Comment: @Wynne misidentified travelers. One switch position is pointlessly shorting the travelers together.  Amateurs replacing 3-ways but who can blame them? 3-ways are about as counterintuitive as wiring gets.

Answer (score 1):

First, here is how 3-way circuits work.

[image]

There are at least 5 different possible arrangements, I picked one that matches your setup.

*These are idealized colors.  Most 3-way wiring is done using multi-conductor cables, and those come with black-white-red from the factory, and nobody ever bothers using colored tape to identify the wires by role.  Thus, colors may not correspond.*

The two travelers are interchangeable.  Swap them if you like, it won't change the functioning of the system.  That's why this diagram uses the same color for both.

Now what we know about travelers is they're always in the same cable.  If the cable is continuous and doesn't stop somewhere, they will be the same pair of colors at both switches.

You notice there is no neutral at all to the right of the light. The white wire in a cable is subject to a priority list:

- If neutral is in the cable, white is it.
- otherwise if always-hot is in the cable, white is it *but it must be marked with paint or tape*.
- otherwise if travelers are in the cable, white must ditto ditto.
- White can *never* be switched-hot.

So your taped white wire going to the black screw is most likely always-hot coming from the lamp.  It goes on a common terminal. Take note of the 2 wire colors on the travelers; the other 3-way should be those most likely.

Comment: My mind is turning to mush as I approach age 80, but Harper it seems to me that your diagram does not show the current paths are restricted by the fact that the different boxes are presumably connected by cables all having at least two current carrying conductors.  You cannot have the supply hot going to the box for switch #1 and the supply neutral going to the load box.

Comment: Don't we first have to know whether the line hot cable enters in a switch box or in the load box?

Comment: I am sure it is unlikely, but what about the possibility that the connection between the two switches is the 3-conductor type in which the commons of the two switches are connected to each other and neither the line hot nor the switched hot to the load are connected to a common? (so called California 3-way switch wiring).

Comment: @Jim yeah, it's a schematic to explain function,  so it omits boxes and wire nuts.  In this arrangement the supply hot would come through the lamp box.  OP provided their cable arrangement, note the black-taped white wire in switch #2. That can only be supply hot, and that indicates a "spur" arrangement like in my diagram. ply at the lamp.